# ¿Cómo modificar apariencia de una ventana utilizando Easygui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interfaz-gráfica, interfaz

Quería mejorar un poco el diseño de la siguiente interfaz gráfica. Está implementada con Easygui porque me estoy iniciando y me parece una opción un poco más asequible que tkinter. Quería saber si puedo cambiar la tipografía y el color de fondo de la siguiente ventana que posee

Así mismo, quería saber si le puedo modificar el logo de la propia ventana

**Ventana:**

```
exto = eg.enterbox(msg='Entrada de texto:',
                                title='Control: enterbox',
                                default='EasyGUI', strip=True,
                                image=None)
```

Por último, quería saber como puedo generar la documentación a partir de un código documentado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BackColor:**

No es posible. La [mejora](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/issues/49) no se ha implementado.

**Font:**

Tienes que ir a alguna de estas direcciones

```
PythonFolder/lib/site-packages/easygui/easygui.py
PythonFolder/lib/site-packages/easygui/boxes/state.py
PythonFolder/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easygui/boxes/global_state.py
```

y modificar

```
PROPORTIONAL_FONT_FAMILY = ("MS", "Sans", "Serif")
```

por la tipografía que desees.

**Documentación**

Podrías utilizar herramientas como [pdoc3](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc/),
[pydoctor](https://github.com/twisted/pydoctor) ó [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/index.html).

Recomendaría hacer una evaluación de cuál se ajusta a tus necesidades, elegir una e intentar generarla.

Si surge alguna duda, sería bueno generar una nueva pregunta en Stack Overflow (recuerda revisar que no esté repetida).